# Create an array from equal values between hash's keys and an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, match, equality

I need to create a new array from equal values between hash's keys and array
For example, I have this:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
my_hash  = { 2 => "Two", 5 => "Five", 7 => "Seven", 10 => "Ten" }
```

And then, I need a new array that contains those equivalent values. In this example, it’ll be:

```
equal_value = [2,5,7,10]
```

How to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
equal_value = my_array.select{|e| my_hash.key?(e)}
```

or (perhaps slower)

```
equal_value = my_array & my_hash.keys
```

Comment: why the second one is slower?